# Stream Stops Working Using FFMPEG Inside a Node Child_Process Spawn

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, child-process

I'm using a video stream on a raspberry pi with raspivid and ffmpeg in a node app. Using them in the terminal (without using node) will stream for hours, but when I use them in a node child_process (I spawn 2, one for each) it works great for a little over 3 minutes and then the stream stops. The child_processes are still running and I'm not seeing any errors.

The gist of my code:

```
let camera = spawn('raspivid', args)
let ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', args)  

camera.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  ffmpeg.stdin.write(data)
})
```

Any ideas why it is stopping after 3 minutes? Thanks!

Comment: pipe the streams

Comment: @Marc - Can you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: Use `camera.stdout.pipe(ffmpeg.stdin)` instead of the `data` event, https://devhints.io/nodejs-stream & https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-stream-pipe  Can you post you ffmpeg args ?

Comment: I had already tried that, but the same problem.

Comment: I found the problem in case anyone else runs into this. I needed to turn off the FFMPEG logging by using the -loglevel quiet argument. Apparently that was filling up the memory in the child process and causing the stream to stop. Works great now!

Answer (score 0):

use video.mkv format
It happened to me in mp4 format and when I switched to mkv it worked out